# Trying to launch jupyter lab in specified browser using .bat file

Tags: python, batch-file, jupyter

I'm trying to launch Jupyter lab in Edge because I use chrome for everything and I like being able to quickly find the tab that has Lab running. I have a .bat script I use, but I can't get it to work with a specified browser. So typing the following in cmd.exe works:

```
call C:\Users\[USERNAME]\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\[USERNAME]\Anaconda3
call jupyter lab --browser "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe %s"
```

But calling this .bat file:

```
call C:\Users\[USERNAME]\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\[USERNAME]\Anaconda3
call jupyter lab --browser "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe %%s"
```

Gives a "no web browser found" message. The echoed commands even match, it just can't find the browser.

Comment: I've tried replacing the / with \ already, problem is the file path is going to get used by python so it will complain about the \. I also tried \\ with no luck. Jupyter itself runs just fine, it's the msedge.exe file path that apparently doesn't work correctly

Comment: Jupyter is a local host, and the %s gets replaced by the URL you would use to talk to it when the server starts up. You're suggestion to take out the call keyword worked though, if you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it. I'm still confused why the exact same sequence of commands works in the command line but not from a .bat file

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure why, but the following .bat file works:

```
call "%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3"
jupyter lab --browser "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe %%s"
```

I'm still confused why commands work differently in the .bat than directly in the command line